# Find value of x in distance formula

Tags: geometry, quadratics

I am trying to find new end coordinates on an existing line. I am working on on **Excel** and finding it hard to find value of x by using distance formula where I know the distance.

I have a line with start points $(x_1,y_1)$ and end points $(x_2,y_2)$. I know the **distance** of the line. I am trying to find out pair of new points where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the still the start point and $(x,y)$ are the new points based on reduced distance on the same line.

I am calculating the equation of line $y = mx + c$ where m is the slope and $c$ is the y-intercept and $m$ is calculated by $m = \frac{y_2-y_1 }{ x_2-x_1}$

Since I know the distance I am trying to compute new points $x$ and $y$ in the distance formula - $distance=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}$ where I compute  $y$ value.

I am trying to write a macro where in I can calculate $x$ value, but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to compute $x$ by substituting **distance** and $y$ in the above formula.

Any suggestions on how to complete this will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $d$ be distance, you have $$d=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}
\\y=mx+c\\d=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(mx+c-y_1)^2}\\
d^2=(m+1)x^2+2(cm-my_1-x_1)x+x_1^2+(c-y_1)^2$$
which is a quadratic in $x$ that you can feed to the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).  There will be two solutions, one each side of your point $(x_1,y_1)$  If you want the solution in the direction of $x_2$ and $x_2 \gt x_1$ you want the sign of $m+1$

Comment: Please share the known distance of the line. This could help!!

Comment: I thought $d$ was given and was the distance along the line from $(x,1,y_1)$ to $(x,y)$.  If it is something else, I have misunderstood.  Please correct me.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Thank you for the answer. I just wanted to know if I am getting this right. In the above final equation `a=(m+1)` and `b=2(cm - my1 - x1)` and `c is (c-y1)` am I right?

Comment: @AtulMishra I am working on a large sets of lines and points which are linked to each other. The distance varies from one line to another. The distance for the line is 75 and second is 89 and so on.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, you are correct, $d$ is given and its the distance from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x,y)$ along the line

Comment: Then you compute the constants in the last equation and plug into the quadratic formula to find $x$.  You then find $y$ from $y=mx+c$ and are done.  If you subtract $d^2$ from both sides the constant term becomes $(c-y_1)^2-d^2$